# Mesecon lua microcontroller print location

Tags: minetest

I am trying to use the mesecon luacontroller for minetest: http://mesecons.net/luacontroller/ the sample code I'm running is:

```
port = {a = true, b = true, c = false, d = true}

print("Hello world")
```

the a b and d ports are all set to true and c is false so I know the code is being executed, however I can't figure out where the console prints to the console used to start minetest, so I tried starting minetest from terminal and it still doesn't print there. I also talked to server admin and it doesn't print to server logs nor the f10 chat window.

In minetest where does the luamicrocontroller print to?

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the linked website:

> `print()` is a great function. It can mostly output anything you want through the console (**the black window that likely started with minetest or the terminal you launched minetest from**)

In other words, if your code is running, it should be printing to the console. If the server admin is checking there and they say they can't see anything, then your code is not running - recheck your conditions.